# Consume .NET 4.6.1 enum from .NET Standard 1.4

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I created a .NET Standard 1.4 project in VS 2017. My solution consists of a bunch of .NET 4.6.1 projects. The new project is intended to be consumed by both .NET Core and .NET 4.6.1 projects.

I added a reference to the domain class (which is 4.6.1) to my .NET Standard 1.4 project. It compiles fine, and I can use objects without any issue. However, if I try referencing an enumeration from the domain class, I get the following error: `error CS0012: The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.`

Enums are supported in .NET Standard of course, I can create one within my project, I am just having an issue referencing one in a .NET 4.6.1 project from .NET Standard 1.4.

**Api.Dto.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="v1\Messages\List\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Domain\Domain.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: "It compiles fine, and I can use objects without any issue." That sounds unusual to start with. You shouldn't be able to add a reference from the netstandard1.4 project to the .NET 4.6.1 project at all. It's not clear why you're seeing this particular error rather than an earlier one, but fundamentally a netstandard1.4 library shouldn't be trying to depend on a .NET 4.6.1 library.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for clarifying that. When I say 'use', I mean I can compile it just fine. I'm in the process of converting to .NET Core, sadly I'm not far enough along to run it yet. I've confirmed in ILSpy that it did compile correctly, however, with the object reference.

Comment: It shouldn't build at all though. Please include the project file you're using to build the netstandard1.4 project - because something very odd is going on here, and you should *expect* that what you're trying shouldn't work.

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated with the CSProj contents

Comment: And `Domain.csproj` is a .NET 4.6.1 project? That really, really shouldn't build as far as I'm aware. When I tried just now, I got an error when building (from the command line): " error NU1201: Project Foo is not compatible with netstandard1.4 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4). Project Foo supports: net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)"

Comment: @JonSkeet 100% .NET 4.6.1. I'm using VS, not the command line to build. Thanks for the clarification however, looks like there is a _lot_ more porting to do!

Comment: Yup - I would ignore the enum part for the minute and focus on moving your net461 project to netstandard1.4. I've no idea how it's even partially compiling at the moment, but I would stop even trying to do that ASAP. Good luck!